# Como puedo realizar un update de un campo al realizar una consulta

Tags: mysql

Ocupo actualizar un campo en tiempo de ejecución, la consulta corre perfectamente lo que no he podido hacer es que me haga el update.

la consulta:

```
    SELECT
control_pat.bienes.Id_Bien AS ID_BIEN,
control_pat.bienes.Activo_Fijo AS ACTIVO_FIJO,
control_pat.bienes.Sub_Activo_Fijo AS SUBFIJO,
control_pat.bienes.Denominacion AS DESCRIPCION,
control_pat.bienes.Numero_Serie AS NUMERO_SERIE,
control_pat.bienes.Fabricante AS FABRICANTE,
control_pat.bienes.Marca AS MARCA,
control_pat.bienes.Modelo AS MODELO,
control_pat.bienes.Material AS MATERIAL,
control_pat.bienes.Color AS COLOR,
control_pat.bienes.Nota_Inventario AS ESTATUS,
control_pat.bienes.Tipo AS TIPO,
control_pat.bienes.Tipo_Activo AS TIPO_ACTIVO,
control_pat.bienes.Numero_Empleado AS EMPLEADO,
CONCAT(plantilla_personal.plantilla.nombre,' ', plantilla_personal.plantilla.apellido1,' ', plantilla_personal.plantilla.apellido2) AS NOMBRE,
control_pat.bienes.Id_modelo AS ID_MODELO,
control_pat.bienes.Id_Tipo_Activo AS ID_TIPO_ACTIVO,
control_pat.bienes.Validacion AS VALIDADO,
control_pat.bienes.Cotejado AS COTEJADO,
control_pat.bienes.Cotejado AS ACTUALIZADO,
control_pat.bienes.Observaciones AS OBSERVACIONES
FROM control_pat.bienes INNER JOIN plantilla_personal.plantilla
ON control_pat.bienes.Numero_Empleado = plantilla_personal.plantilla.numero_empleado
WHERE CONCAT(control_pat.bienes.Activo_Fijo,control_pat.bienes.Sub_Activo_Fijo) IN('101165681')
AND control_pat.bienes.Numero_Empleado = 111
```

Esto me regresa todos los valores, y ocupo por una condición del sistema que se actualice el campo : control_pat.bienes.Cotejado de 0 a 1 al ser encontrado el numero empleado y su respectivo activo.

alguna idea ?

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu pregunta. Esta es una consulta `SELECT`, ¿qué tendría que ver un `UPDATE`  aquí?. ¿A qué te refieres con *en tiempo de ejecución*?

Comment: Podrias mostrar el resultado de tu SELECT para ver que es lo que quieres lograr

Comment: A. Cedano, ocupo que se actualice un campo antes de mostrar el resultado, he visto en algunos foros que si es posible pero no he logrado que me funcione a mi.

Comment: Edgar Vazquez. el resultado que me arroja es un datatable donde ocupo que me aparezca el estatus como de cotejado.

Comment: Eso es lo que no entiendo... ¿quieres un `SELECT` que a la vez te haga un `UPDATE`  o qué es lo que quieres?

Comment: Así es C. Cedano la idea es que se actualice el campo, cuando la consulta se ejecute correctamente.  Aqui el problema es que no funciona cuando hay mas de dos activos...

Comment: Pero ese select no es dinamico o si por lo que entiendo no?

Comment: No es dinamico , es solo una consulta a la BD para que obtenga los "valores" que se requiere mostrar, pero por una necesidad en particular, requiero que se actualice ese campo antes de que se muestre,  la otra opcion es que el update lo hiciera despues del select, en base a los resultados de la consulta, quizas un if o algo asi...

Comment: A mi me parece un *requerimiento* muy extraño tener que estar actualizando datos al tiempo que se seleccionan y me pregunto si no hay un error de concepción o de lógica en tu aplicación. ¿Qué es lo que justifica que esos datos tengan que actualizarse? ¿No sabes que eso podría ser muy costoso para la base de datos, estar actualizando datos permanentemente? ¿Son datos calculados? ¿Deberían existir realmente en las tablas o sería más conveniente calcularlos en aquellos contextos donde se necesiten? etc... En fin, yo trato de ir más lejos en el problema.

Comment: Quizás falta el contexto de la aplicación, es un sistema de control patrimonial, antes de que te muestre la consulta, se realiza una captura desde una pistola laser para codigos de barras,  se pretende que al pulsar un boton,  todo lo que se haya capturado con la pistola se actualice el campo "cotejado" y al finalizar la consulta te muestre en un datatable que esos activos fueron encontrados en la base de datos, a lo mejor existe otra forma de hacerlo pero de momento fue como se me ocurrio que podria hacerse, no sin antes investigar en muchos foros, pero no me resulto.

Comment: Para casos como estos el contexto es muy importante. Por ejemplo tu comentario anterior aclara muchísimas cosas. Si es como dices, no se trata entonces de un `SELECT` que a su vez haría un `UPDATE`. Si entendí bien, cuando se escanea con la pistola la intención es actualizar los registros que tienen ese código ¿? y posteriomente mostrar que esos registros fueron actualizados ¿? Si es así, entonces es justo lo contrario, un `UPDATE` que a su vez muestre qué registros fueron actualizados.

Comment: Si es correcta tu apreciacion, solo se requiere validar que el codigo de barras capturado corresponde a un empleado y el activo este registrado a el, la idea es que se actualice el campo y mostrar el resultado en una datatable, lo que no haya sido capturado con la pistola se muestra en otra tabla, y si hubo una captura de un producto nuevo, se muestra en otra vista igual de un datatable...

Comment: Quizá lo mejor para esto sea crear una función que haga todas esa verificaciones que dices: si el código corresponde a `X`, si es un producto nuevo, si hay que actualizar el registro, etc. Esta función recibiría en parámetro uno o varios códigos los cuales se usarían para actulizar, luego para consultar y devolver el conjunto de datos que esperas para mostrar en la datatable. Si hay más lógica a aplicar, se aplica dentro de la función...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés que utilizar la clausula **UPDATE** indicarle el campo, valor nuevo, nombre de la tabla y condiciones.

Para tu caso sería:

```
UPDATE control_pat.bienes
 SET Cotejado = 1
WHERE CONCAT(Activo_Fijo,Sub_Activo_Fijo) IN ('101165681') 
AND Numero_Empleado = 111
```

Comment: Nicolas ya lo intente asi, lo que tengo un problema la lista dentro del IN, puede crecer debido a que es una captura con una pistola de codigo de barras, y ahi es donde truena, en el proyecto no funciona , por fuera en MySQL Query Browser si funciona

Comment: ya intente colocando primero la sentencia completa del update así como lo describes y al finalizar esta que haga el select (que puse al inicio de la pregunta)  para un activo si funciona correctamente, ya cuando hay mas de 2, no hace el update.

Comment: Si la respuesta no es la correcta no la deberias de marcar como tal

Comment: Se agradece el aporte, es funcional para un activo, quizás hay que revisar algo o modificar alguna parte del código para que sea funcional para mas de 2 activos.  Agradezco la atencion que me brindan, igual sirve de motivación a seguir adelante.  Saludos